# Answers referencing another answer for the same question

Tags: discussion

Can a mod please clarify why this answer would not qualify to be deleted (and instead should have been posted as a comment.)

This is literally the posted answer ( see here: [How to Rename Theme Folder in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152142/how-to-rename-theme-folder-in-magento2/152145#152145))

> Follow above step
>
> Give Write recursive permission to Design folder

The answer just references the post above, which one who knows? and I got banned for raising flags for 7 days for raising the flag 2 times. Seems a little extreme for something that IMO isnt an answer, nor does the OP think so and someone else in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I don't know why you insist on deleting that post. does it do that much harm to the website?
I explained it when I declined your flags. It does not violate any rules. It's not a single link answer, it's not spam, it's not duplicating and existing answer, it just adds something to one of them (which ever that might be).
There are a lot of other answers in here that come as additional information to one of the other answers.
Is it a wrong answer or the OP does not like it? I don't know and I don't care. If you think it's wrong you should downvote it, not flag it.
As for your ban from flagging things, I think this is done automatically when your second flag on the same post is declined. I didn't do it.
I'm investigating now how to get your ban revoked, if it's possible.

Comment: I think from next week he can raised the flag. this ban is temporary for current week only

Comment: My position is that he could have added that as a comment. If the original answer above that answer is removed, it makes no sense. We will agree to disagree, as for the ban if its automatic thats fine Ill come back in a week.